# Здравствуйте! проблема в том, что Fastapi не парсит данные в виде json'a переданные со странички браузера, как можно решить эту проблему? Спасибо

Tags: python, fastapi

```
import base64
import hmac
import hashlib
import json
from typing import Optional


from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Cookie, Body
from fastapi.responses import Response

app = FastAPI()

SECRET_KEY = "f6974803655d6825b481cb476818be35ec015d48d743bfe4a56a989d85bbc368"
PASSWORD_SALT = "ee8849520dacf49a68dbba523fea3cc704ef3b3dcd21cb1a7ba1a59a89a02d06"

def sign_data(data: str) -> str:
    '''Возвращает подписанные данные data'''
    return hmac.new(
        SECRET_KEY.encode(),
        msg=data.encode(),
        digestmod=hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest().upper()
    
def get_username_from_signed_string(username_signed: str) -> Optional[str]:
    username_base64, sign = username_signed.split(".")
    username = base64.b64decode(username_base64.encode()).decode()
    valid_sign = sign_data(username)
    if hmac.compare_digest(valid_sign, sign):
        return username

def verify_password(username: str, password: str) -> bool:
    password_hash = hashlib.sha256( (password + PASSWORD_SALT).encode() )\
        .hexdigest().lower()
    stored_password_hash = users[username]["password"].lower()
    return password_hash == stored_password_hash

users = {
    "alexey@user.com": {
        "name" : "Алексей",
        "password" : "fc551e507987011145ed58a29dd324731c1b477f1446dafec62583642869fc10",
        "balance" : 100_000
    },
    "petr@user.com": {
        "name" : "Пётр",
        "password" : "71d474a34ffe47000bbf243f906bbaf8ef4816568de3ba13a5326ea122fa1a31",
        "balance" : 555_555
    }
}

@app.get("/")
def index_page(username: Optional[str] = Cookie(default=None)):
    with open('templates/login.html', 'r') as f: 
        login_page= f.read()
    if not username:
        return Response(login_page, media_type="text/html")
    valid_username = get_username_from_signed_string(username)
    if not valid_username:
        response = Response(login_page, media_type="text/html")
        response.delete_cookie(key="username")
        return response
    
    try:
        user = users[valid_username]
    except KeyError:
        response = Response(login_page, media_type='text/html')
        response.delete_cookie(key="username")
        return response
    return Response(
        f"Привет, {users[valid_username]['name']}!<br / >"
        f"Баланс: {users[valid_username]['balance']}", 
        media_type='text/html')
    

@app.post("/login")
def process_login_page(data: dict = Body(...)):
    print('data is', data)
    password = data["password"]
    username = data["username"]
    user = users.get(username)
    if not user or not verify_password(username, password):
        return Response(
            json.dumps({
                "success" : False, 
                "message" : "Я вас не знаю!"
            }), 
            media_type="application/json")
    
    response = Response(
        json.dumps({
            "success" : True,
            "message" : f"Привет, {user['name']}! <br /> Баланс: {user['balance']}"
        }),
        media_type="application/json")

    username_signed = base64.b64encode(username.encode()).decode() + "." + \
        sign_data(username)
    response.set_cookie(key='username', value=username_signed)
    return response
```

в `def process_login_page(data: dict = Body(...)):` почему то не парсится json в виде пароля и логина, не знаю в чем причина, в браузер ответ приходит ошибкой -

```
detail: [{loc: ["body"], msg: "value is not a valid dict", type: "type_error.dict"}]
```

Вот пример странички сайта:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Личный кабинет</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 

    <style type="text/css">
    input {
        display: block;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        outline: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    form{
        width: 90%;
        min-width: 250px;
        max-width: 350px;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0; padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: ghostwhite;
    }
    .placeholder{
        flex: 1;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        let btn = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
        btn.addEventListener('click', async function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            let username = document.querySelector('input[name=username]').value;
            let password = document.querySelector('input[name=password]').value;
            let response = await fetch("/login", {
                method: "POST",
                body: `{"username": "${username}", "password": "${password}"}`
                //body: new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))
            });
            let response_json = await response.json();
            console.log(response_json);
            if (response_json.success){
                let body = document.querySelector('body');
                body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                body.style.display = "block";
                body.innerHTML = response_json.message;
            }

        })
    })
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <form method="POST" action="/login">
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Войти" />
    </form>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Наверное, стоит их передавать в том виде, в котором их ожидает увидеть FastAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается не установил заголовок `Content_type`:

```
let response = await fetch("/login", {
            headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
            method: "POST",
            body: `{"username": "${username}", "password": "${password}"}`
```

Такая проблема вышла из-за новой версии Fastapi, начиная с 0.70.

Answer (score 0):

В поле body убери кавычки:

body: {"username": username, "password": password}

И в файле main.py добавь CORS middleware, почитай документацию на офф.сайте.
Проблема в том что браузер не разрешает твоему серверу отправлять данные и наоборот
Вот ссылка:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/

Comment: Вариант с кавычками отлично работает, просто нужно было только установить заголовок Content-type
Спасибо за помощь)